# Angular 7 / Ionic 4 Select the selected option

Tags: angular, typescript, select, angular7, ionic4

I have the following code which simply makes dynamic drop down select (). I want to get the value of the selected items.

The loop makes 3 to 5 or even more different  based on API data.

Now I want to know which of these values the user selected and submit them. Currently my "shop now" button does nothing. I tried many ways but I had no luck. Can somebody sort this out please?

When we click on the shop button the value/ids of selected items should be printed in the console.

Screenshot is attached for reference, thanks in advance.

[image]  [image]

```html
      <ion-card>
        <div *ngFor="let item of currentItem.DealRuleDealCode; let i = index">
          <div *ngFor="let CT of item.CategoryType; let j = index ">
            <ion-grid>
              <ion-row padding-left padding-right>
                <ion-col size="6" no-padding>
                    <ion-label class="catName">{{CT.CategoryName}}: </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                  **<ion-select ok-text="Okay" cancel-text="Dismiss" no-padding class="select" (ionChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)" >
                    <ion-item *ngFor="let SC of CT.SubCategory; let k = index" >
                      <ion-select-option [value]="SC.SubCategoryCode" selected >{{SC.SubCategoryName}} </ion-select-option>
                    </ion-item>
                  </ion-select>**      
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ion-grid>
          <hr />
          <ion-row>

              <ion-col size="6" no-padding>
                <ion-button fill="solid" color="light"  expand="full" size="">
                  <label class="bold"> {{currentItem.Price | currency : 'PKR'}} </label> 
                </ion-button>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col size="6" no-padding>
                <ion-button fill="solid" color="light" (click)="shopNow()" expand="full" size="" class="bold">
                  <label> Shop </label>  
                  <ion-icon name="add-circle" slot="end" >ADD</ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
              </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>

      </ion-card>
```

This is my shopNow() function.

I just want to get all the selected values in my this shopNow() Function. But I don't know how....?

```
shopNow(){

}
```

Here is my TypeScript file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray  } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ProductsService } from '../services/products.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-detail',
  templateUrl: './menu-detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-detail.page.scss'],
})

export class MenuDetailPage implements OnInit {

  currentItem:[];

  selectedValues:[] = [];
  //selectedItems = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductsService, private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentItem = this.productService.currentItem;

    if(this.currentItem.length < 1){
      this.router.navigate(['main/menu'])
    }
  }


  selectChangeHandler(event){
    console.log(event.target.value) 
  }

  shopNow(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saleem, can we have a look at the TypeScript file? The Ionic code looks good, there's probably a problem inside the shopNow() function.

Comment: Dear @FrancoRoura, Thank you for your kind response. current I don't have any useful think. I tried to implement some of my own logic, but nothing worked for me. Can you kindly suggest some way to get all the selected values inside this function?

Comment: Btw you have a type its `Beverages`

Answer (score 0):

The value of your select is in `value`:

```
<ion-select [value]="selectvalues[j]" ok-text="Okay" cancel-text="Dismiss" no-padding class="select" (ionChange)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
```

You need to understand that you are building an Angular two-way binding system.

It's not a case of presenting the information and then collecting it later on.

You create a model for your data, and it's updated in real time as the user selects each option.

In your code you need an array, like I have suggested selectvalues[], which can hold the data. Something like:

```
public selectvalues: any[] = [];
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head if that will be enough, or if you will have to push empty items into the array (to match the number of `item.CategoryType` you are displaying). You will have to experiment with this.

Comment: Sir what if I only post this like a normal HTML form without two way binding? the VALUES I already have there. Just need to submit with the selected values